# Javascript conditional compilation in GWT JSNI

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni, conditional-compilation

I have this conditional compilation statement which evaluates whether the browser is `IE` or not:

```
ie = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
if (ie) {
 //do IE specific stuff..
}
```

I need to use it in GWT within JSNI. However when I do this:

```
public native void JS()  /*-{
 ie = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
}-*/;
```

I am getting an error on that line like **Syntax error, } expected**. I tried to `eval` it, still the error persists. How can I fix it?

Comment: That's not a Regular expression, but an JScript-specific feature called [conditional compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahx1z4fs(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: No? Oh then, what is it? I thought so from the delimiting slashes, even though the regexp made no sense to me...

Comment: It's called [conditional compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Conditional_comments_in_JScript). No RegExp involved.

Comment: Is there any way to `eval` it? I need to use it in JSNI within GWT, but GWT is throwing an error on this line.

Comment: @Cupidvogel GWT? Please include the relevant tags and information in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/*@cc_on!@*/` is not a regular expression, but a multi-line JavaScript comment (`/* .. comment .. */`). In Internet Explorer, this is more than a comment. The code is parsed and evaluated (this feature is called [conditional compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahx1z4fs(VS.80).aspx)).

The `*/` in your code ends the GWT-specific `/*-{` section, causing the error to show up.

The solution is to use a different way to write down the comment:

```
var ie = false;
//@cc_on ie = true;
```

Another method, also safe against JavaScript minifiers is:

```
var ie = eval('/*@cc_on!@*'+'/false');
```

Comment: @Cupidvogel Both methods are verfied in IE9. The original eval-thing was missing a second `@`, causing an error. I've added it.

Comment: I'm curious. Is this browser detection method secure against User Agent Sniffing? Is there any side-effects for eval'ling conditional compilation code, for IE detection?

Comment: @LeonardoMontenegro This feature cannot be spoofed as easily as the user agent string, so yes, it will reliable detect the JScript engine. However, IE11 has dropped support for conditional compilation, so it can only be used to detect IE10-.